# Woocommerce - Redirect users based on username

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to redirect certain usernames to a chosen URL when logged on.

I did try the below but it did not work.

https://www.cozmoslabs.com/docs/profile-builder-2/developers-knowledge-base/redirect/redirect-based-username/

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried the below code in my functions but did not work.

```
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
// Get user name
$username = $user->user_login;

// Conditions
switch ( $username ) {
     case 'rosinarep':
        $redirect = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( '/product-category/gifting/' ) );
        break;
     default:
        $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
}
return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10,        2 );
}
```

Comment: Never edit your questions. Just add comment as additional details. You never get Category URL from `get_permalink( get_page_by_path( '/product-category/gifting/' ) );`.

Comment: To get category URL, use this code. `get_category_link( get_cat_ID( 'Your Category Name' ) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try below code snippet in your theme's `functions.php` file or custom  plugin file.

```
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
    // Get user name
    $username = $user->user_login;

    // Conditions
    switch ( $username ) {
         case 'admin':
            $redirect = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'sample-page' ) );
            break;
         case 'username1':
            $redirect = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'sample-page-2' ) );
            break;
         case 'username2':
            $redirect = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'sample-page-3' ) );
            break;
         case 'username3':
            $redirect = get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'sample-page-4' ) );
            break;
         default:
            $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
    }
    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Also please confirm that you have already created all this redirect pages.

Check below link to get more details about this filter.

http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_login_redirect/